# NSCompositingOperationSourceAtop, NSCompositingOperationPlusLighter not working in Mojave

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, macos-mojave

In Mojave 10.14 beta, composite modes no longer work for me in certain situations.
Mojave forcing layer-based NSView drawing breaks a great deal of custom NSView drawing.

NSCompositingOperationSourceAtop / NSCompositeSourceAtop draws nothing... completely broken!  I would at least expect to draw a crappy unaliased source image.
(EDIT: it draws something only if you first draw a non-clear background color.  If you fill with [NSColor clearColor] first, it draws nothing)

NSCompositingOperationCopy does work.

NSCompositingOperationPlusLighter / NSCompositePlusLighter does not draw a lighter image than the background color.  I guess that's to be expected since layers know nothing about parent layers' background color.

Here's some relevant source code (NSCompositeCopy draws image, NSCompositeSourceAtop draws nothing):

```
  NSImage *myImage = blahblah;
  [myImage drawInRect:targetRect fromRect:imgRect operation:NSCompositeSourceAtop fraction:1.0];
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem using NSCompositingOperationSourceIn for drawing a progress bar on top of an NSTextField toolbar item (to emulate Xcode's status bar). The progress bar color gets blended with the NSTextField background color, which now possibly has some opacity? The source in formula is R = S * Da. So I guess if the entire background has some alpha then my drawing operation will get affected by that alpha.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the Core Animation alpha 'rules' changed at some point.  It used to be that a compositing operation on a completely clear layer would be treated as a copy.  Now it seems to multiply by 0 alpha, so you always get nothing.  The old way was much more useful... please bring it back, Apple!

Comment: I fixed my problem switching to NSButton subclass, which probably is a better base class anyway and it renders correctly.